# How should I clean surfaces where a mouse may have walked or touched, but not pooped?

Tags: safety, cleaning, pest, mice

A mouse got into my cabinet. There are a few poops in there; I cleaned those up and cleaned the affected area with bleach solution.

I'm going to improve my food storage situation, catch the mice, and check closely for other areas where they have been. **But I have a more specific question about how to clean up:**

I know where the mouse pooped (that cabinet), but they were likely in more areas beyond just that cabinet. There's no poop anywhere else, but maybe they left pee? Viruses? I don't know. **How should I clean those areas?** It's a big area, and some of it is not very friendly to bleach. Is there some other chemical I can use? Do I even need to clean areas like this? Will the diseases and stuff just go away over time?

I'm in the US midwest, in an urban area but we get a lot of critters like raccoons and stuff coming around. I mention that in case it's relevant to the regional diseases.

Comment: Use the bleach based cleaner suggested here: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/290610/97780

Answer (score 3):

Give any suspect area a quick wipe down with whatever cleaners you use on your cabinets/counter tops, then stop panicking.

Funny thing... the mice were probably there for weeks before you noticed any droppings and you weren't worried then and it didn't cause you problems then, either.

Comment: Lysol, 409... anything but the smell of bleach stuck in my nose for the next two days.

Comment: I'm not a bleach fan either, @Mazura, but whatever makes people happy and relieves their irrational fears.

Answer (score 1):

Could try an enzymatic cleaner.

Comment: This is not a complete answer, and should have been a comment. Feel free to edit it with more information, such as why you think this should be attempted, or whether you've used this in a similar situation and what the outcome was.

Answer (score 1):

You could try oxygen bleach, a.k.a. non-chlorine bleach, as commonly used as an additive for laundering clothes., made up to the suggested strength for hand-washing (wear rubber gloves, of course), if it makes you feel better to have used a strong cleaner. Plus it often has a nice smell added to it.

I am not a bacteriologist/virologist.